# logstash(2.3.2) gzip codec not work

Tags: plugins, logstash, codec

I'm using logstash(2.3.2) to read gz file by using gzip_lines codec.
The log file example (sample.log) is

```
127.0.0.2 - - [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3891 "http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

The command I used to append to a gz file is:

```
cat sample.log | gzip -c >> s.gz
```

The logstash.conf is

```
input { 
  file {
    path => "./logstash-2.3.2/bin/s.gz"
    codec => gzip_lines { charset => "ISO-8859-1"}
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    #match => { "message" => "message: %{GREEDYDATA}" }
  }
  #date {
  #  match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  #}
}


output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have installed gzip_line plugin with bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-codec-gzip_lines

start logstash with ./logstash -f logstash.conf

When I feed s.gz with 
cat sample.log | gzip -c >> s.gz

I expect that the console prints the data. but there is nothing print out.

I have tried it on mac and ubuntu, and get same result. 
Is anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked the code for `gzip_lines` and it seemed obvious to me that this plugin is not working. At least for version 2.3.2. May be it is outdated. Because it does not implement the methods specified here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/_how_to_write_a_logstash_codec_plugin.html

So current internal working is like that:

- `file` input plugin reads file line by line and send it to codec.
- `gzip_lines` codec tryies to create a new GzipReader object with GzipReader.new(io)
- It then go through the reader line by line to create events.

Because you specify a gzip file, `file` input plugin tries to read gzip file as a regular file and sends lines to codec. Codec tries to create a GzipReader with that string and it fails.

You can modify it to work like that:

Create a file that contains list of gzip files:

```
-- list.txt
/path/to/gzip/s.gz
```

Give it to file input plugin:

```
file {
    path => "/path/to/list/list.txt"
    codec => gzip_lines { charset => "ISO-8859-1"}
}
```

Changes are:

Open `vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-codec-gzip_lines-2.0.4/lib/logstash/codecs/gzip_lines.r` file. Add `register` method:

```
public
def register
  @converter = LogStash::Util::Charset.new(@charset)
  @converter.logger = @logger
end
```

And in method `decode` change:

```
@decoder = Zlib::GzipReader.new(data)
```

as

```
@decoder = Zlib::GzipReader.open(data)
```

The **disadvantage** of this approach is it wont tail your gzip file but the list file. So you will need to create a new gzip file and append it to list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a variant of this problem where I needed to decode bytes in a files to an intermediate string to prepare for a process input that only accepts strings.

The fact that encoding / decoding issues were ignored in Pyhton 2 is actually really bad IMHO. you may end up with various corrupt data problems especially if you needed to re-encode the string back into data.

using ISO-8859-1 works for both gz and text files alike. while utf-8 only worked for text files. I haven't tried it for png's yet.

Here's an example of what worked for me

```
        data = os.read(src, bytes_needed)
        chunk += codecs.decode(data,'ISO-8859-1')
        # do the needful with the chunk....
```